# How to initialize a Controller's computed property to model in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a computed property `myArray` defined on an Ember controller that returns an array. The array should be initialized to the contents of `model` and then recompute by filtering `model` depending on a user-input query.

```
myArray: function() {
  // return a value that filters model with query
}.property('model', 'query')
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do both at the same time. The below does not work to initialize `myArray` to `model`; I'm guessing because model is loaded asynchronously and `init()` runs before it's finished.

```
// doesn't work
init: function() {
  this._super();
  this.set('myArray', this.get('model'));
}
```

So I thought that `setupController()` would be the place to set it, but I found that setting `myArray` there caused the filter update not to work, maybe because I was overwriting the definition.

```
// route definition...
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
  controller.set('myArray', model);  // breaks updating
}
```

How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a computed property depending on `model` - you don't have to initialize it, it just has to return the right thing.

```
// untested, just to show the idea
myArray: function() {
   var query = this.get('query');
   var model = this.get('model');

   if (query) 
      return doSomethingWith(model, query);
   else
      return model;
}.property('model', 'query')
```

Since it is a property, the initializing and updating will take place for itself.

That said, Twitter lore is that the usage of `.property` shall be discouraged, better use `Ember.computed`.

```
// untested, just to show the idea
myArray: Ember.computed('model', 'query', function() {
   var query = this.get('query');
   var model = this.get('model');

   if (query) 
      return doSomethingWith(model, query);
   else
      return model;
})
```

It's just another way to write it, and may be mor future-proof in the long run.

Comment: Setting the value will not overwrite the computed property, it will call the computed property like a setter, as explained [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/object-model/computed-properties/).

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I've changed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
myArray: function() {
  this.set('myArray', this.get('model');
}.property('model', 'query')
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I don't know why I went with the roundabout way of doing things. I guess I just wanted to illustrate that computed properties act as setters too. This will also work the same way:

```
myArray: function() {
    return this.get('model').filter(function(item) {
        return (item.property_you_want_to_filter_by === true);
    });
}.property('model.@each.property_you_want_to_filter_by', 'query')
```

The [Ember shorthand](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filter) will also work:

```
myArray: Ember.computed.filter('model', function(item) {
    return (item.property_you_want_to_filter_by === true);
});
```

---

You need to take advantage of the fact that computed properties are getters *and* setters.

```
myArray: function(key, value) {
    // This is the setter
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        this.set('_myArray', value);
    }

    // This is the getter
    // Do your filtering with `query` here
    return this.get('_myArray').filter(function(item) {
        return (item.selected === true);
    });
}.property('_myArray', 'query')
```

Since you only set it when you get a new model, you can just store the value in a private property on the controller (in this case `_myArray`). Then for the getter, you can use the value stored in that property combined with your query to return the value you want. In my example above, I've filtered out every non-selected item.

Comment: The "Ember shorthand" is missing 'model' as first parameter. That said, if the filter is indeed some logic supported by the included filter function, this would indeed be the shortest version.